# How to install (or simply run?) vmware's converter from Linux?

Tags: software-installation, vmware, sh

I'm looking for **specific instructions** for this, noting that [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) can give ***general*** guidance.

---

In other words, what to do with `VMware-converter-6.2.0-7348398.odp.tgz` (*)?

*The answer to this might be plain obvious, but since a quick search did not give any helpful results and the [guide on vmware.com](https://www.vmware.com/pdf/convsa_60_guide.pdf) is only for the Windows-based installation, I figured it would be worthwhile asking here.*

(*) <sub>downloaded (for free, after registering) from [here on my.vmware.com](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/info?slug=infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/6_2_0). See also [this unanswered question on communities.vmware.com](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/584143).</sub>

---

```
/tmp/VMware-converter-6.2.0-7348398.odp$ ls
bash-4.1           iconv-1.9.2                  reiserfsprogs-3.6.19
build_ttylinux.sh  iptables-1.4.9.1             SYSTEMS.txt
busybox-1.11.1     libiconv-1.9.2               tar-1.28
busybox-1.18.4     libmspack-0.0.20040308alpha  test
e2fsprogs-1.40.11  libparted-3.1                ttylinux-12.6
e2fsprogs-1.41.12  log4cpp-1.0                  udev-163
efibootmgr-0.5.4   lvm2-2.02.95                 util-linux-ng-2.18
extract_helper.sh  module-init-tools-3.12       vmware-sysinfo-1.0
glib-2.24.2-1      net-tools-1.60               xfsprogs-3.2.2
glibc-2.12.1       package_helper.sh
grub-0.97-75       procps-3.2.7-1
```

---

content of `SYSTEMS.txt`:

> The following systems are used when building this VMware disclosure.
>   The domain "example.org" is used in this document to define systems.
>   Please adjust this domain and hostnames to match your environment.
>
> "rhel-7.3-x32"
>       This is a Red Hat EL 7.3 system.  The ISO images for this install are
>       available at http://redhat.lsu.edu/dist/7.3/iso/  This system should
>       be configured with at least 32 Gb of disk space to accomodate build.
>       A kickstart file to configure this system is is available in the
>       directory config/rhel-7.3-x32.cfg along with a floppy image
>       file (rhel-7.3-x32.flp) containing this ks.cfg file.  The 7.3 system does
>       not support kickstart files over http, the floppy image should be used
>       instead.  The system should be configure using the boot prompt command
>
> ```
> linux ks=floppy
>
> after attaching the floppy image to the diskette device.
>
> The kickstart file includes a "%post" section which
>
> * Configures the system to automount the shared file server used to
>   host the VMware Toolchain disclosure.  Please adjust the hostname
>   for this server in the kickstart file.
>
> * Creates the user "vmware" with a home directory of "/usr/vmware".
>   The directories under this home directory are used when building
>   disclosed packages.
>
> The passwords defined by the kickstart file for the "vmware" user is
> "welcome".
>
> No internet based updated are applied to this system.  The "as installed"
> system is used when building package.
>
> For your reference, the ISO images used by VMware for this system were
>
> cb91810ce8173039fed24420407e4c59  valhalla-i386-disc1.iso
> ec1b813d32ffdc8edc2be261735d17de  valhalla-i386-disc2.iso
> 5dc81ce523cfddf99b4d4d63e91bcaa7  valhalla-i386-disc3.iso
>
> NOTE: A similiarly configured system is used when building the VMware
>       Toolchain disclosure.  However, that system is not configured to
>       automount the shared file server: the %post sections differ.
> ```
>
> "centos-4.8-x32"
>       This is a CentOS 4.8 32-bit system.  This system should be
>       configured with at least 16 Gb of disk space to accomodate builds.
>       A kickstart file to configure this system is is available in the file
>       "config/centos-4.8-x32-ks.cfg".  The file should be stored on a web
>       server, e.g., "ns.example.org" and the system should be configure
>       using the boot prompt command
>
> ```
> linux ks=http://ns.example.org/centos-4.8-x32-ks.cfg
>
> The kickstart file includes a "%post" section which
>
> * Configures the system to automount the shared file server used to
>   host the VMware Toolchain disclosure.  Please adjust the hostname
>   for this server in the kickstart file.
>
> * Creates the user "vmware" with a home directory of "/usr/vmware".
>   The directories under this home directory are used when building
>   disclosed packages.
>
> The passwords defined by the kickstart file for both "root" and "vmware"
> are both "welcome".
>
> No internet based updated are applied to this system.  The "as installed"
> system is used when building package.
>
> For your reference, the ISO image used by VMware for this system was
> (MD5 checksum):
>
> f663dfc0a0ee610d23c223468004c745  CentOS-4.8-i386-binDVD.iso
> ```
>
> "centos-5.3-x32"
>       This is a CentOS 5.3 32-bit system.  This system should be
>       configured with at least 16 Gb of disk space to accomodate builds.
>       A kickstart file to configure this system is is available in the file
>       "config/centos-5.3-x32-ks.cfg".  The file should be stored on a web
>       server, e.g., "ns.example.org" and the system should be configure
>       using the boot prompt command
>
> ```
> linux ks=http://ns.example.org/centos-5.3-x32-ks.cfg
>
> The kickstart file includes a "%post" section which
>
> * Configures the system to automount the shared file server used to
>   host the VMware Toolchain disclosure.  Please adjust the hostname
>   for this server in the kickstart file.
>
> * Creates the user "vmware" with a home directory of "/usr/vmware".
>   The directories under this home directory are used when building
>   disclosed packages.
>
> * Disables services not required when building disclosures.
>
> The passwords defined by the kickstart file for both "root" and "vmware"
> are both "welcome".
>
> No internet based updated are applied to this system.  The "as installed"
> system is used when building packages.
>
> For your reference, the ISO image used by VMware for this system was
> (MD5 checksum):
>
> 997638cd72a559e38f9fd1955a368231  CentOS-5.3-i386-bin-DVD.iso
> ```
>
> "centos-5.3-x64"
>       This is a CentOS 5.3 64-bit system.  This system should be
>       configured with at least 16 Gb of disk space to accomodate builds.
>       A kickstart file to configure this system is is available in the file
>       "config/centos-5.3-x64-ks.cfg".  The file should be stored on a web
>       server, e.g., "ns.example.org" and the system should be configure
>       using the boot prompt command
>
> ```
> linux ks=http://ns.example.org/centos-5.3-x64-ks.cfg
>
> The kickstart file includes a "%post" section which
>
> * Configures the system to automount the shared file server used to
>   host the VMware Toolchain disclosure.  Please adjust the hostname
>   for this server in the kickstart file.
>
> * Creates the user "vmware" with a home directory of "/usr/vmware".
>   The directories under this home directory are used when building
>   disclosed packages.
>
> * Disables services not required when building disclosures.
>
> The passwords defined by the kickstart file for both "root" and "vmware"
> are both "welcome".
>
> No internet based updated are applied to this system.  The "as installed"
> system is used when building packages.
>
> For your reference, the ISO image used by VMware for this system was
> (MD5 checksum):
>
> 6d4fd59688ed8644514010316d6a5698  CentOS-5.3-x86_64-bin-DVD.iso
> ```
>
> "freebsd-6.3-x32"
>       This is a FreeBSD 6.3 32-bit system.  This system should be
>       configured with at least 16 Gb of disk space to accomodate builds.
>       A kickstart file is not available for this system.  Please install
>       using the
>
> ```
>     Standard Begin a standard installation (recommended)
>
> installation option.  When the "Choose Distributions" menu is displayed
> please select the distributions
>
>     X-Developer
>     Kern-Developer
>     X-User
>
> The install should be performed against CD/DVD media.
>
> For your reference, the ISO images used by VMware for this system were
> (MD5 checksum):
>
> cdb0dfa4b2db3e4c9cc19138f4fb2ada  6.3-RELEASE-i386-disc1.iso
> e73a3d9cf5f3bfbf07384ef0a93ae5d5  6.3-RELEASE-i386-disc2.iso
> 123840107a5578ce22875c440d41f453  6.3-RELEASE-i386-disc3.iso
> ```
>
> "freebsd-6.3-x64"
>       This is a FreeBSD 6.3 64-bit system.  This system should be
>       configured with at least 16 Gb of disk space to accomodate builds.
>       A kickstart file is not available for this system.  Please install
>       using the
>
> ```
>     Standard Begin a standard installation (recommended)
>
> installation option.  When the "Choose Distributions" menu is displayed
> please select the distributions
>
>     X-Developer
>     Kern-Developer
>     X-User
>
> The install should be performed against CD/DVD media.
>
> For your reference, the ISO images used by VMware for this system were
> (MD5 checksum):
>
> a8d41ea26769919db6c0c672fa8f8c4f  6.3-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso
> a243076fb99b011d9b0771a6f7f9a977  6.3-RELEASE-amd64-disc2.iso
> 92831414b34b4b06cfb7140ddfe69cfe  6.3-RELEASE-amd64-disc3.iso
> ```
>
> "windows-xp-x64"
>       This is a Windows XP Professional 64-bit. Please perform the following steps:
>
> ```
> 1. Install Windows XP Professional 64-bit.  VMware uses Microsoft 32 bit    compilers on a 64 bit system to build the 32 bit Toolchain.
>
> 2. Install Visual studio 2008 Professional Edition.
> * Install everything under Visual C++ Language Tools including X64 Compilers
>  & Tools
> * Apply the SP1 patch from
>    http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en
>  to your visual studio installation.
>
> 3. Copy the following to c:\toolchain\win32\bin
>
> Copy fromdos.exe and todos.exe - http://tofrodos.sourceforge.net/download/tfd1712a.zip
>
> Copy usr/local/wbin/* from UnxUtils - http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/UnxUtils.zip/download
>
> Install Cygwin and then copy "sh.exe", and "cp.exe", and "tar.exe" (and various cygwin
> dlls required to run them) from the Cygwin installation.  At the time of
> publishing, the commands to do this are:
>
>   $ cd \Toolchain\win32\bin
>   $ copy \cygwin\bin\sh.exe sh.exe
>   $ copy \cygwin\bin\cp.exe cp.exe
>   $ copy \cygwin\bin\tar.exe tar.exe
>   $ copy \cygwin\bin\cygwin1.dll cygwin1.dll
>   $ copy \cygwin\bin\cygintl-8.dll cygintl-8.dll
>   $ copy \cygwin\bin\cygiconv-2.dll cygiconv-2.dll
>   $ copy \cygwin\bin\cygreadline7.dll cygreadline7.dll
>   $ copy \cygwin\bin\cygncursesw-10.dll cygncursesw-10.dll
>   $ copy \cygwin\bin\cyggcc_s-1.dll cyggcc_s-1.dll
>   $ copy \cygwin\bin\cygattr-1.dll cygattr-1.dll
>
> 4. Copy over the Windows toolchain binaries for win32 and win64 from the shared file    system to the below folders:
>
>   C:\toolchain\win32
>   C:\toolchain\win64
>
> 5. Please use Visual Studio 2008 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt to build 64-bit
> binaries and use Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt to build 32-bit binaries.
>
> 6. Add C:\toolchain\win32\bin to PATH
>
>   $ set PATH=C:\toolchain\win32\bin;%PATH%
>
> NOTE: A similiarly configured system is used when building the VMware
>       Toolchain disclosure.
> ```

---

```
$ sudo find . -print | grep -i 'install'
[sudo] password for _______________________: 
./xfsprogs-3.2.2/INSTALL.txt
./e2fsprogs-1.40.11/INSTALL.txt
./busybox-1.18.4/INSTALL.txt
./grub-0.97-75/INSTALL.txt
./iconv-1.9.2/INSTALL.txt
./busybox-1.11.1/INSTALL.txt
./libiconv-1.9.2/INSTALL.txt
./e2fsprogs-1.41.12/INSTALL.txt
./log4cpp-1.0/INSTALL.txt
./glib-2.24.2-1/INSTALL.txt
./tar-1.28/INSTALL.txt
./udev-163/INSTALL.txt
./iptables-1.4.9.1/INSTALL.txt
./util-linux-ng-2.18/INSTALL.txt
./reiserfsprogs-3.6.19/INSTALL.txt
./ttylinux-12.6/INSTALL.txt
./procps-3.2.7-1/INSTALL.txt
./glibc-2.12.1/INSTALL.txt
./bash-4.1/INSTALL.txt
./libmspack-0.0.20040308alpha/INSTALL.txt
./net-tools-1.60/INSTALL.txt
./net-tools-1.60/net-tools-1.60-installlib.patch
./lvm2-2.02.95/INSTALL.txt
./efibootmgr-0.5.4/INSTALL.txt
./vmware-sysinfo-1.0/INSTALL.txt
./module-init-tools-3.12/INSTALL.txt
./test/sysinfo-install.sh
./test/helper-install.sh
./libparted-3.1/INSTALL.txt
```

Comment: `.tgz` is an abbreviation for `.tar.gz`. I strongly recommend using `checkinstall` and `auto-apt` for the installation, see [this help.ubuntu.com article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall).

Comment: @dessert even with these it seems dishearteningly complicated ... :-(

Comment: It does? Extract the archive with `tar -xzf FILENAME` and `cd` into the newly created directory. Usually now it’s just `auto-apt run ./configure && make && sudo checkinstall` (provided you installed the two of course) and you’re done.

Comment: The instructions in the generic post do not apply to the case...